# Oracle as file Database

Tags: c#, oracle

Is there a possibility to create and access Oracle Database files from anywhere in the file system? I want to connect with C# and Entity Framework or NHibernate.

Background is we need to create a folder in the filesystem which represent a project and contains

- the database itself
- a very complex file and folder structure

the user wants to copy the folder to a new PC, and work with this project

I know SQL Server compact supports such scenario but we need Oracle as DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Oracle has no feature like that. Database files are created on the database itself, and they aren't as portable as SQL Server database files.

Comment: Actually, the location of Oracle's data files is not exactly hard to find out; and in most cases, the DBA decides where to place them und how large to make them.

Comment: Yes, but you can't 'just' copy/paste deploy them like you do with SQL Server.